# Laravel upgrade strategy

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a very old app running on Laravel 4.2 that I want to upgrade to ideally Laravel 7 or 8. I'm wondering if I need to go through the upgrade incrementally from 4.2 to 5.0 to 5.1 etc until the desired version or is there a more efficient and time-saving way? BTW, I've heard of LaraUp which upgrades 4.2 to 5.8 and Laravel Shift but I haven't get around to try them out. Would appreciate some ideas or thoughts here.

Thanks!

Comment: I have had good experiences with https://laravelshift.com/. Be warned that going from Laravel 4 to Laravel 7/8 is still going to be a slog; the automated tools can only go so far, and yes, the easiest way is going to go from 4 to 5 to 6 to 7 to 8 so it's not as overwhelming.

Comment: If I were you, I would upgrade the version to 8 at once. That would be more time-saving. Hardest part would be deprecated and unmanaged dependencies, not the laravel framework itself

Comment: We had a similar question going from Laravel 3 to 5.3 back when that was the latest version. It turned out to be quicker to simply rewrite the route and controller skeleton code and then move the code around appropriately, rewriting parts that were not compatible. From what I understand L4 is a lot more similar to L8 than L3 was to L5 so I would expect it to be the better route. However expect it to require lots of work, there's just no easy way around that.

Comment: Found a blog post regarding this upgrade.. might be worth taking a look https://arobs.com/blog/my-experience-upgrading-laravel-framework-5-8-to-8-x/